# Magento 2: image issue in jspdf

Tags: magento2, javascript, pdf

I am using jspdf library to generate pdf and I am unable to print images on the pdf.

here is my code:

```
 require(['jquery','jsPDF'], function ($,jsPDF) { 
        var logo = 'https://rugs.a2hosted.com/pub/media/logo/stores/1/4.png';
     
        $('.print_button_pdf').click(function (){ 
               var lo = $('#pro').val();
            var doc = new jsPDF(); 
            var carName = $(".main_pro_title").html();
            //doc.addImage(logo, 'PNG', 10, 10, 60, 15);
            doc.setFontSize(12);
            doc.text(150, 15,'Tel : +44 (0) 027-965-7366');
            doc.line(0, 30, 600, 30);
            doc.setFontSize(20);
                        //doc.setTextColor(255, 0, 0);
                          getDataUri(logo, function (logoUri) {
                    getDataUri(lo, function (dataUri) {
                            doc.addImage(logoUri, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 60, 15);
             doc.text(10, 40,carName);
             
             doc.addImage(dataUri, 'JPEG', 10, 50, 110, 80);
                  
             var kvi_start_top = 50;
                        var kvi_left_start_name = 130;
                        var kvi_left_start_value = 170;
                        var kvi_height_inc = 8;
                        
                        //key vehicle information
        doc.setFontSize(13);
        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'KEY VEHICLE INFORMATION');
        kvi_start_top +=10;
        
        doc.setFontSize(10);
        //kvi_brand
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Brand');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_brand").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_body_type
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Body Type');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_body_type").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_color
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Colour');
    doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_color").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_engine
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Engine');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_engine").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_fuel_type
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Fuel Type');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_fuel_type").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_location
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Location');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_location").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_miles
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Miles');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_miles").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_owners
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Owners');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_owners").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_registration
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Registration');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_registration").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_trans
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Transmission');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_trans").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_year
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Year');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_year").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                        //kvi_price
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_name, kvi_start_top,'Price');
                        doc.text(kvi_left_start_value, kvi_start_top,$("#kvi_price").val());
                        kvi_start_top +=kvi_height_inc;
                        
                            //features list
                            
                            //Features
                        var desc_start = kvi_start_top+15;
                        
                        doc.setFontSize(13);
                        
                        doc.text(10, desc_start,'Features');
                        doc.setFontSize(9);
                        var line_one_start_top = desc_start +5;
                        var line_start_left = 10;
                        var line_item_inc = 50;
                        var features = $(".kvi_featrues");
                        
                        //contact
                        var conatct_start = line_one_start_top+15;
                        doc.setFontSize(13);
                        doc.text(10, conatct_start,'Contact');
                        doc.setFontSize(11);
                        conatct_start +=5;
                        doc.text(10, conatct_start,'LONDON & ESSEX');
                        conatct_start +=5;
                        doc.text(10, conatct_start,'TEL. 0207 965 7366');
                        conatct_start +=5;
                        doc.setFontSize(10);
                        doc.text(10, conatct_start,'www.jaguarwarehouse.co.uk');
                        conatct_start +=5;
                        doc.text(10, conatct_start,'info@jaguarwarehouse.co.uk');
                        conatct_start +=5;
            doc.save(carName+'.pdf');
                    });});   
                         
        });    
    });
    
         function getDataUri(url, callback) {
             console.log(url);
                    var image = new Image();
                    image.setAttribute("crossOrigin", "https://rugs.a2hosted.com");
        
                    image.onload = function () {
                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas.width = this.naturalWidth; 
                        canvas.height = this.naturalHeight; 
        
                        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
                        callback(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));
                    };
        
                    image.src = url;
                }
```

Any help would be appreciated.